# Node Web Scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have simple web scraper on Node and i have problem to point out which data i want to scrap. Someone can help? I want to take text from "entry clearfix" div. [img of dom structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdX0i.jpg) And my problem is what query shoudl i use. I have code like this:

```
$('.entry clearfix').filter(function(){
var data = $(this);
zmiany = data.children().text().trim();
```

And i dont know how to point out a data from "entry clearfix" div.

Comment: Try `$('.entry.clearfix')` for starters :-)

Comment: Jesus... Thank you very much i am such a moron.